# is $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_1 =$ {$X \subset \mathbb{R}: X \textrm{ or } \mathbb{R} \setminus X \textrm{ is countable}$ } countably generated?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Given that we have a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_1$ such that

$\mathcal{F}_1 =$ {$X \subset \mathbb{R}: X \textrm{ or } 
 \mathbb{R} \setminus X \textrm{ is countable}$ }

Is $\mathcal{F}_1$ countably generated? If it is not countably generated, how can I show it?

Thanks,

Comment: I think so. so if $\mathcal{F}_1$ countably generated?

Comment: hello, I've edited my original post

Comment: thank you. your notation is right

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by operations

Comment: Do you mean countably generated as a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: I just want to know whether $\mathcal{F}_1$ is countably or uncountably generated $\sigma$-field

Comment: I edited my question again

Comment: If $\mathcal E$ is a countable subset of $\mathcal F$, then there is a countable set $A$ of real numbers such that every member of $\mathcal E$ is either a subet of $A$ or the complement of a subset of $A$.

Comment: I am still confused

Comment: @bof: $\mathscr{F}_1$ is countably generated as a $\sigma$-field if it is the smallest $\sigma$-field containing some countable subfamily of itself. Here that is not the case.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so....$\mathcal{F}_1$ is not countably generated?

Comment: @vverdic: That’s correct.